# Unable to resolve "./SafeAreaProviderCompat" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/src/views/BottomTabView.tsx"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm building an expo react native app (sdk 46.0) and when loading the app I am confronted with the error in the title. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their might be some issue with the package. I remember once I encountered some errors with the bottom tab navigation. what i did was that i tried some previous versions and one of them worked for me.

so what i recommend.

1] first kill the terminal , make new terminal and start expo using

expo start -c

This will clear the cache. Then Check if it works.

Sometime we also have to close the software itself that we are using for development like (vs studio) and then re open it and try step 1.

2] Try re-installing the same Package. Their might be a possibility it's not correctly installed and repeat step 1

3] Try to install previous versions. That may work and repeat step 1

Also Check your imports. Thanks. (Hope this resolves your issue)